# Prime Number check and play again function

Tags: c++

I'm currently taking C++ and one my assignments is to create a program that checks if the number is a prime number correctly handle the invalid
integer inputs. In addition, user should be able to test as many integers as he or she wants in a single run. In other words, the program should not end unless the user tells you to.

I understand the prime number check part but I cannot figure out to implement the "test as many integers as you want in a single run and handling invalid input"

Any comments and edits to the code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
using namespace std;
int main () {

    int num, i, count = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number to be checked : ";
    cin >> num;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n" << num << " is not prime";
        exit(1);
    }
    else   {
            for(i=2; i < num; i++)
                if (num % i == 0)
                    count++;
    }
    if (count > 1)
        cout << "\n" << num << " is not prime.";
    else
        cout << "\n" << num << " is prime.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: test as many integers means it s a loop(eg while loop ), check for invalid input means check if the input aint an integer for example :) eg :  your int n you do std::cin>> n to read the user input into the int n & then check if (cin.good()) the rest is up to you to do :)

Comment: First thing to determine is how the user is to signal that they wish to input no more numbers. You can do very little else, including asking a question about how to do loop until the user wishes to exit the loop, without determining how the user's going to tell the program to exit.

Comment: Side note: When you get that far, look into prime number sieves (mugh faster than what you are currently doing) and memoization (to prevent recomputing prime numbers found in previous requests).

Comment: Search keyterm: *Input validation*

Comment: @user4581301 I know I can use a do/while loop but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: That's part of it, but what is the user expected to input, instead of a number for the primality test, to signal that they want out of the loop?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes [1] No [2]

Comment: For that you want a function that keeps pestering the user and refuses to return until they provide a 1 or a 2 `int getContinue() { int choice; while (cin >> choice and choice != 1 and choice != 2) { /* clean up error and prompt user for new input */ }` This function is called in the `while` condition.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you write it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you can try. After input the number, the program will ask whether you want to continue or not by inputting `y` or `n`.
If the user input `y`, the program will keep looping and ask the question again otherwise it will break the loop. 
Last note : don't use `using namespace std` (bad habit)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {

    int num, i, count = 0;
    char flag;
    while(1)
    {   
        std::cout << "Enter the number to be checked : ";
        std::cin >> num;
        if (num == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n" << num << " is not prime";
        }
        else   {
                for(i=2; i < num; i++)
                    if (num % i == 0)
                        count++;
        }
        if (count > 1)
            std::cout << "\n" << num << " is not prime."<<std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "\n" << num << " is prime."<<std::endl;

        std::cout <<"Do you want to continue? [y/n]";
        std::cin >> flag;
        if (flag == 'n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can change the `y/n` to another char or string or int or whatever you want

Comment: Ok so I ran into a problem where the exit(1); was not declared

Comment: It should work fine. What compiler and IDE (program) are you using?

Comment: I'm using MobaXterm

Comment: Nevermind, updated the code. I just remove the `exit(1)` after cout

Comment: Thank you so much again, would you be willing to help me with another assignment?

Comment: Depends on your assignment. Just post your next question if you have one, and I''ll check when I have free time